# ENS Long lost bids

Tags: metamask, ens

A year ago I made some bids for ENS names over at ens.domains but never revealed. Those bids and domains have now expired or passed on to other hands. I have about 0.25 ETH still locked away there. How can I unlock that ETH?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found my answer

> If for any reason you failed to reveal your bid during the designated “reveal” period, your entire deposit is burned :-(

So no unlocking or releasing those funds